# Ambiguous usage of "too" at the end of a sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar

> 'I heard *Avengers* is awesome too.'

Does this mean that I heard *Avengers* is **also** an awesome movie, or I **also** heard that *Avengers* is awesome?

Basically I want to convey that I also heard from others that *Avengers* is awesome. Is the first sentence correct?

Comment: It depends entirely on the context. It's impossible to know the meaning without additional information. If you want to be unambiguous (barring any other surrounding sentences), then just say *I **also** heard that* Avengers *is awesome.* Exactly as you did your question. But if you're *replying* to somebody who says that it's awesome, your sentence will be easily understood in the second sense (the one you want).

Answer (score -2):

No, what you want to say is *I too heard Avengers is awesome*. So you use 'too' in the same way and position you would use 'also' in 'I also heard that this movie is awesome'.

The phrase you gave instead conveys that Avengers is awesome like something else that is awesome too.

Comment: Very true, but "I, too..." sounds a bit formal for a chat about films. You could say something like "I  heard that too - that _Avengers_ is awesome".

Comment: Agreed, yet in a 'chat about films' the original quote would do just as fine, wouldn't it? prk would convey his/her intent acoustically there if it wasn't obvious by context anyway. So yeah, I answered from the POV of conveying the message on the page.